# Possible Conditionals

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

1-***I am sorry if I have offended anyone.***

2-***I’m sorry if I offended anyone.***

Are these sentences grammatically correct ? And the "if parts" refer to past or present ? And if the "if part" refer to past why dont we use these sentences:

3-***I am sorry if I'd had offended anyone.***

4-***I am sorry if I'd offended anyone.***

Answer (score 1):

The first two sentences are grammatically correct. But they are not conditional. Don't be confused by *if* because it's **not** used in conditionals ***only***.

**I'm sorry if + clause** is used to apologize for something, and **not** to introduce the circumstances in which an event or situation might happen, might be happening, or might have happened (like in conditionals). The function is different, and so is the grammar.

The choice of the tense after *I'm sorry* depends on the situation:

> I'm sorry if **I have offended** anyone. *(use the Present Perfect to emphasize the connection with the present. It's not clear when you possibly caused offense, but the point is someone might be offended now - that's the connection with the present which the Present Perfect shows)*
>
> I'm sorry if **I offended** anyone. *(use the Past Simple to show there is no connection with the present. Maybe you offended someone in the past but it's all history now)*
>
> I saw you, guys, down in the dumps. I'm sorry if **I had offended** you. *(use the Past Perfect to show that you might have offended someone before you saw the people sad).*

So, neither of the sentences above is conditional. Compare them with the conditionals below:

- I **will** be sorry if I **offend** anyone. *(1st conditional)*
- I **would** be sorry if someone **were offended**. *(2nd conditional)*
- I **would have** been sorry if I **had offended** someone. *(3rd conditional)*

Comment: Thanks , how can I understand conditional if clauses from non conditional if clauses ? I think conditional forms need modal verbs such as : will/would/can/could

Comment: @TalhaÖzden I'd recommend thinking about the function. What is the person trying to do: apologize or explain a condition? Note that the sentence "I am always sorry if such things happen" is conditional, though there are no modals in it. But the if-clause is about the condition under which I feel sorry (by the way, this type of conditional is called zero conditional). But "I'm sorry if I've made a mistake" is apologetic and not conditional.

Comment: I have one more sentence confusing my mind . "if you have finished your dinner go back to your room." so is it a conditional sentence ? if so what kind of conditional is it ?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden it is a conditional sentence. But the interesting thing is that the main clause is imperative. "if you have finished your dinner" is the sub-clause with the present perfect tense in it. It's OK, if we use present tenses in the sub-clause, the whole conditional becomes real. The three sentences at the end of my answer are all unreal conditionals. So, "if you have finished your dinner, go back to your room" is a real conditional with the imperative mood in the main clause. If you need more information on conditionals, check this out https://enguroo.com/2018/06/08/conditionals/.